# Azure Datafactory , multi level complex csv structure

Tags: azure-data-factory

We have to deliver a rather complex csv structure and we would like to use Data factory for this.
The structure has multiple levels with a global header and trailer+ a subheader (per topic) and it's detail lines.
The first column defines which type of line it is. I've simplified the real format just to highlight the questions I have.

HEADER - common data like export date and number sequence
SUBHEADER - topic name 1
DETAIL - detail line of above topic
DETAIL - detail line of above topic
DETAIL - detail line of above topic
SUBHEADER - topic name 2
DETAIL - detail line of above topic
DETAIL - detail line of above topic
DETAIL - detail line of above topic
TRAILER - A closing line with total linecount

The source data would be the detail lines + the topic name.

There are 2 problems I'm unable to solve :

1. How do I convert the source data into the complex SUBHEADER + DETAIL format. To be honest no clue on how to approach this.
2. Is there a way to add the global header + trailer with total linecount via Datafactory? An alternative would be doing this with an azure function.

All suggestions are welcome ...

Regards,
Sven Peeters

Comment: Where is the source data coming from?  eg a database, .csv in your data lake, parquet, something else?

Comment: It would be coming from a csv in a datalake. It would be possibly thousands of small csv files that need to be combined into one big export file. The source data 'trickles' in during the day while the export happens once a day.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a couple of choices with Azure Data Factory:

- take an ELT approach where you use some type of compute (eg a SQL database, Databricks, Azure Batch, Azure Function or Azure Synapse serverless SQL pools if you're working in Synapse) to do the hard work structuring the file and outputting it.  ADF is really just doing the orchestration (telling other processes what to do in what order) and handling the output.  The compute is handling the fiddly bit.
- take an ETL approach and use Mapping Data Flows.  This is a low-code approach which uses on-demand Spark clusters in the background.  You do not have to manage them.

I would be tempted to use SQL to do this, particularly if you already have some in your infrastructure.  A simplified example:

```
;WITH cte AS (
SELECT 10 sortOrder, 'someHeader' main
UNION ALL
SELECT 20, 'col1, col2, col3'
--FROM someTable
UNION ALL
SELECT 30, 'someFooter'
)
SELECT main
FROM cte
ORDER BY sortOrder;
```

If you've got time, why not try both approaches as a proof-of-concept, see which works best for you, your data and your organisation.  Look at factors such at time to develop, maintainability, how flexible, cost etc

Comment: Thank you for the elaborate explanation. I was afraid that the Data Factory approach would be the wrong one, this confirms my fear. Back to the drawing board, I'm considering an Azure function for this topic.

Comment: I think ADF is a fine choice for this, I'm just trying to explain you have (at least) two options, and with option 1 it's ADF plus something else, and with option 2 you need to configure the low-code pipeline.  Maybe someone will do an example of option 2 for you.  For me, I would not move large volumes of data across an Azure Function.